# UMVUE of $\theta$ for $\mathrm{Uniform}(0,\theta) $ where $\theta \in[1, \infty)=\Theta$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution, umvue, complete-statistics

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from $\mathrm{U}(0, \theta)$, where $\theta \in[1, \infty)=\Theta$, say. Here I tried to find complete-sufficient statistics for $\theta$ as my main target is to get a UMVUE of $\theta$. I discover that $T=X_{(n)}$ is not complete for $\theta$ by taking a counter-example $g(t)= \cos(\pi t)/nt^{(n-1)}$ for $0<t<1$ when $\theta \in \Theta$.

But how we can get a Complete-Sufficient statistic of theta when parametric space is restricted. I have searched a lot of books to get some idea of finding a Complete-Sufficient Statistic or UMVUE in the restricted Parametric Space. I have faced a lot of problems on MLE in Restricted Parametric Space but not the UMVUE.

Comment: This problem is discussed in the lecture notes here: https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-31.pdf.

Comment: I do not understand the counterexample, as $\mathbb E_\theta[g(T)]$ is not constant in $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks @StubbornAtom for sharing.

Comment: I got the counterexample by considering$$g(t)=\begin{cases} \cos(\pi t)/nt^{(n-1)}&\text{when }0<t<1\\0&\text{when }t\ge 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes. @Xi'an .I have to write this expression completely. I am editing my question. Actually, I want to describe what you have written, but I think I forget to write the $t>=1 $ part. Thanks for correcting me.